# Issues while accessing Jenkins using IP address vs DNS Name (with AD integration)

Tags: apache, nginx, jenkins, dns

Noob Question: 
I have a Jenkins instance setup on an internal team domain (with our own DNS/AD configured). This domain is inside the intranet. 
We have security enforced on Jenkins using the Active Directory plugin. Therefore, all users login with their AD credentials for an actions like triggering a job, etc. Viewing is open to all. 
We access the Jenkins instance using the DNS name (http://jenkins.team.company.com:8080). However, when accessing certain jobs, the address changes to http://10.XX.XX.XX:8080/../..). At this point, the users' logged in sessions are also terminated. 
I am at a loss about what is causing the sessions to get lost. 
(in the spirit of full disclosure - this Jenkins instance does not have an nginx or apache running in front of it. Until recently, this was my own local Jenkins instance but now the ask is to get everyone to start using this. I am wondering whether setting up nginx or Apache will resolve the problem. You can tell that I have none or very little background with running Web Applications)

Comment: On Jenkins configuration page (Manage Jenkins, Configure System), did you provide the correct value in `Jenkins URL` field?

Comment: I had not. Correcting that fixed the issue.